# Function parameter that has inferred type has no intellisense in the return , while it has in the rest of the function body

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Here is the code where this problem occurs:

```js
function component<T>(p: {
    actions : () => T,
    htmlTemplate: <S extends T>(actions : S) => any
}) {
    return p;
}

component({
    actions : () => ({
        a : (x,y) => x+y
    }),
    htmlTemplate : (actions) => { 
        /*try to dot into the actions and you will get intellisense*/ 
        actions;
        /*but if you dot here you will get no intellisense*/ 
        return actions;
        /*
        intellisense appears in the `return actions` If I type `x` and `y`
        how can I have no problem with intellisense wihtout providing types for `x` and `y`?
        */
    }
})
```

In the `htmlTemplate` function body , the `actions` parameter has intellisense but it does not in `return` .

1. Why does that happen ?

The problem with intellisense stops when I type `x` and `y` of `actions` .

2. How to make intellisense work without typing `x` and `y` ?

I am using vscode and my project has no `tsconfig.json` file .

Edit : An ugly "solution" would be to do this :

```js
const component = <T>(p1: {
    actions: () => T
}) => (p2: {
    htmlTemplate: <S extends T>(actions: S) => any
}) => Object.assign({}, p1, p2)

component({
    actions: () => ({
        a: (x, y) => x + y
    })
})({
    htmlTemplate: (actions) => {
        actions;
        return actions;
    }
});
```

and intellisense does work .

Comment: Depending on how you TS compiler is configured. I have the `noImplicitAny` flag set to true, so the `(x, y) => x + y` expression is not allowed. Whenever I type both `x` and `y` (no matter if I set to `any`) I get the `actions` intellisense on the `return` statement. Not sure why is behaving like this... Anyways, `noImplicitAny` is an almost-must flag to have.

Comment: @VRoxa I have no `tsconfig.json` in my project . `noImplicitAny` does not solve the issue . For some strange reason I have to explicitly type `x` and `y` and the intellisense works even if I type them with `any` , which by the way when they get that type implicitly the intellisense does not work . It really seems to me like a bug . 
Also the `component` function is supposed to be used by javascript projects that will not have `tsconfig.json` files . So in the end explicitly typing is not an option .

Comment: Well... Since you are using TS, implicit typing should not be the way to go. And, of course this will be run by a JS engine, as all of TS code. TS allows to have a nice and secure development env, which is accomplished by typing all the stuff.

Comment: @VRoxa When someone is using the `component` function in a javascript project , he will not be able to type each function parameter in the `actions` object , so intellisense in `htmlTemplate` will not work since the parameters will have implicit any .